# Vector2.Normalize function, confused about diagonal output

Tags: c#, xna

My question is when using the Vector2.Normalize function (in XNA specifically)

It's probably my bad understanding of vector maths but as I understand it, Normalizing gives you a direction, or a gradient.

If you apply a speed in a single direction such as up down left and right it'll just return plus or negative 1 for the specific axis and the direction that makes sense to me.

But say if I ask to normalize a vector2 where moving diagonally, say 1 unit down for every 1 unit right.  It returns this.

{X:0.7071068 Y:0.7071068}

This surprises me as I would've thought it would've been more like [X:0.5 Y:0.5]

My reasoning for this?  If one direction is absolute value of 1 and another is the absolute value of 1 the other way, shouldn't moving at a 45 degree angle produce a midpoint of something like 0.5?

and wouldn't the 0.5 and 0.5 added produce the magnitude of 1 I thought a normalized vector was supposed to adhere to?

I don't know if I can see an answer for myself using something like DYDX as it's just a direction, not some line with a known end point.

Comment: Normalizing a vector keeps the direction but sets its length to 1, so I don't see why this would be wrong. 0.707 is 1/sqrt(2). Thus the length is sqrt(1/sqrt(2)**2 + 1/sqrt(2)**2) = 1.

Comment: Where is the programming question here? If you have some problem with undestanding of normalized direction vectors, then you'd better read some relevant info and ask a question on math.stackexchange. If you have some programmatical problem that is caused by current representation of vectors - describe it with code, desired and current results.

Comment: Apologies, now I understand the maths behind it a bit better I realise it's more suited to a maths exchange like you say.  I wasn't finding the right resources earlier.  I wasn't sure if the way the Vector2.Normalize method handles normalization was somehow different to how it would be in standard maths until I understood the answer it gave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a visual aid. Normalizing always makes a vector have a length of 1.0. So the 3 vectors in the image are all equal length of 1.0. the x & y coordinates of the diagonal vector are obviously greater than 0.5f
[image]